# How can I attempt to solve this problem concerning injective/surjective functions?

Tags: functions

I don't know why, but I am having issues solving problems where I have to show whether a function is surjective/injective. It seems that I just cannot apply definitions properly.

Here is the problem and my attempt to solve it.

Show that if $ f: X \rightarrow Y $ is a surjective function, then there exists $g: Y \rightarrow X $ satisfying $f \circ g(y)=y $ for all $y \in Y$.

My attempt:

As $f$ is surjective, for all $y \in Y$ there exists $ x \in X$ s.t. $f(x) = y$.

I was given the property $f \circ g(y)=y $ for all $y \in Y$ therefore I can say that for all $y \in Y$ we must have $f(g(y)) = y $ which seems to get me nowhere. I know that $ f(x) = f(g(y))$ but I can't equate $x$ and $g(y)$, as I don't know whether $f$ is injective. Great. Now I am stuck.

Can someone please point out what I should do next (or what I should redo)? How should I approach these types of problems in general?

Answer (score 1):

This uses the axiom of choice. For each $y\in Y$ choose a $x\in f^{-1}(y)$ and let $g(y)=x$. There is an $x\in f^{-1}(y)$ since $f$ is surjective.